# Proxy exceptions when using $http_proxy env var?

Tags: proxy, shell

In a typical browser, when we set a proxy server, we can define a list of hostnames/IP addresses that are not to use the proxy server. How do we accomplish the same thing when using $http_proxy? I rely on setting $http_proxy to use the proxy server in [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) on Linux but they're certain IP addresses on the intranet that I need to bypass the proxy settings for.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try setting variable named `no_proxy` in following manner

```
$ export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
```

But if you do this in the command line, you will have to do it again each time you open a new terminal window. If you want those settings to be persistent, put this very command inside your .profile file
under $HOME ([read this answer if you want to understand better what this .profile file is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/345845)).

Comment: Is `NO_PROXY` and `no_proxy` equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

A very helpful answer. I would add that if you're using curl/wget or other command line tool, you'd want to do:

export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16